# Castle Windsor auto registration

Tags: castle-windsor

I currently have the following registration set up

```
private static void AddFrameworkComponentsTo(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    container.AddComponent<ITypeConverter, TypeConversionFacade>();
    container.AddComponent<Framework.Conversion.ITypeConverter<string, int>, StringConverter>();
    container.AddComponent<Framework.Conversion.ITypeConverter<string, decimal>, StringConverter>();
    container.AddComponent<Framework.Conversion.ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>, StringConverter>();
}
```

What's the easiest way to avoid having to register each interface to the same component? As you can see, my "StringConverter" class implements several different interfaces, and the list is likely to grow.

**Edit**
I've just realised that the above doesn't even work because complains about the key, so had to change it to below:

```
container.AddComponent<Framework.Conversion.ITypeConverter<string, int>, StringConverter>("ITypeConverter<string, int>");
container.AddComponent<Framework.Conversion.ITypeConverter<string, decimal>, StringConverter>("ITypeConverter<string, decimal>");
container.AddComponent<Framework.Conversion.ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>, StringConverter>("ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>");
```

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: the code above should work just fine, what exception do you see about the key? what version of Windsor are you using?

Comment: "There is a component already registered for the given key MyCompany.Framework.Conversion.StringConverter"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(StringConverter).GetInterfaces())
                            .ImplementedBy(typeof(StringConverter)));
```

See the [fluent API wiki](http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API) for more information on fluent registration.

Comment: thanks mausch that worked... wish I could get my heard around the registration syntax, problem is I don't use it enough.